# Se me presenta un problema en java al ejecutar una consulta sql para mostrar registros en un jtable

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Se me presenta este problema con este método para mostrar datos de una bd en java, pues me dice que la consulta no genero ningún resultado al momento de guardar en mi formulario y necesito guardar y que de inmediato me muestre el registro, este codigo lo muestra pero tengo que salirme del proyecto y volver a meterme para ver los registros y lo que quiero es que al ingresar se muestre inmediatamente, les agradecería la respuesta

```
void MostrarDatos(){
    DefaultTableModel modelo=new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo.addColumn("Rif");
    modelo.addColumn("Cedula");
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
    modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
    modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
    modelo.addColumn("TR");
    modelo.addColumn("TC");
    modelo.addColumn("Direccion");
    datalistado.setModel(modelo);
    String []datos = new String [8];
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cliente");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            datos[0]=rs.getString(1);
            int IDENTIFICADOR = (int)rs.getInt(2);
            String NUMERODEIDENTIFICADOR =                 String.valueOf(IDENTIFICADOR);
            datos[1]=NUMERODEIDENTIFICADOR;
            datos[2]=rs.getString(3);
            int TELEFONO = (int)rs.getInt(5);
            String NUMERODETELEFONO = String.valueOf(TELEFONO);
            datos[4]=NUMERODETELEFONO;
            datos[5]=rs.getString(6);
            datos[6]=rs.getString(7);
            datos[7]=rs.getString(8);
            modelo.addRow(datos);
        }   
        datalistado.setModel(modelo);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Clientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que tenes? Inserta el registro en la base de datos, pero no muestra inmediatamente en tu JTable?

Comment: @josego exactamente

Comment: y la parte de tu código donde insertas en la base de datos?

Comment: @josego el codigo excede el limite de caracteres pero esto es basicamente lo que hace

Comment: @josego el codigo es este  PreparedStatement pat= cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cliente(rif,identif,nombre,apellido,telefono,tipo_rif,tipo_identif,direccion_fiscal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: En la parte de insertar en la base de datos al final de la linea agregaste  datalistado.setModel(modelo);??

Comment: no es que no declaro un modelo en ninguna parte del agregar @josego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes de hacer es, a la hora de hacer una inserción a la BD y que se refleje en tiempo de ejecución en el JTable es avisarle al modelo de tu JTable que los datos están por cambiar.

Ejemplo:

```
tabla.setModel(m);    //la tabla se actualiza. m es el modelo
```

Answer (score 1):

Hace falta decirle al `DefaultTableModel` que se han hecho cambios:

Luego de hacer la inserción en la base de datos agrega lo siguiente:

```
modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Que según la los [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29):

> Notifies all listeners that all cell values in the table's rows may
>   have changed. The number of rows may also have changed and the JTable
>   should redraw the table from scratch. The structure of the table (as
>   in the order of the columns) is assumed to be the same.

En español:

> Notifica a todos los escuchadores de eventos que todos los valores de
>   celdas en las filas de la tabla han podido cambiar. El número de filas
>   también pudo haber cambiado y el JTable debería re-dibujar la tabla
>   desde cero. La estructura de la tabla (tales como el orden de las
>   columnas) es asumido que siguen igual.

Comment: pero en mi insertar tendria que desclarar ese DefaultTableModel y luego hacer lo que me dices una ves que inserto pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo que la consulta no genera respuesta

Comment: @estabanrincon  
pero en mi insertar tendria que desclarar ese DefaultTableModel y luego hacer lo que me dices una ves que inserto pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo que la consulta no genera respuesta